# Xamarin Forms Webview EvaluateJavascript Error en IOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Tengo una aplicacion hecha en Xamarin Forms, la cual trabaja en Android y IOS.

La aplicacion esta hecha desde Windows en Visual Studio 2019 y funciona bien en los emuladores de Android y IOS, pero cuando la paso a un dispositivo fisico de IOS(IPhone) no funciona correctamente.

Uso un webview para invocar un javascrit de terceros y ese javascript lo mando a llamar a la hora de hacer mi login.

Leyendo encontre que aparentemente mi error se presenta por el cambio que hizo Apple de cambiar UIWebview a WKWebview, pero hasta ahorita no he encontrado como resolverlo.

Este es mi codigo:

LoginPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyLogin.Views.LoginPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
           
            <Label Text="Sign In" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Title" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="50" />
            <Entry x:Name="emailEntry"
            Grid.Row="2"
            BackgroundColor="#31FFFFFF"           
            Placeholder="Email"
            PlaceholderColor="#3AAAF4" />
            <Entry x:Name="passwordEntry"
            Grid.Row="3"
            Margin="0,0,0,0"
            BackgroundColor="#31FFFFFF"
            IsPassword="True"
            Placeholder="Password"
            PlaceholderColor="#3AAAF4" />
            <Button Text="Login" Clicked="OnLoginButtonClicked" BackgroundColor="#3AAAF4" TextColor="White" CornerRadius="8"  />
            <Label></Label>
            <Label x:Name="messageLabel" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" WidthRequest="50" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" />
            <WebView x:Name="webView" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsVisible="false" />
        </StackLayout>

    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

LoginPage.cs

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Plugin.DeviceInfo;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using System.Web;

namespace MyLogin.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
    {
        public string BlackboxString = "";

        public LoginPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            webView.Source = LoadHTMLFileFromResource();
        }
             
        async void OnLoginButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         
            var blackbox = "";
           
            blackbox = await webView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync($"getBlackbox()");          


            //Code to login
        }

  
      
        private string GetLocalAddress()
        {
            var IpAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()).FirstOrDefault();

            if (IpAddress != null)
                return IpAddress.ToString();

            return "Could not locate IP Address";
        }

        HtmlWebViewSource LoadHTMLFileFromResource()
        {
            var source = new HtmlWebViewSource();

            // load HTML embed in PCL
            var assembly = typeof(MainPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("mypage.mypagename.html");
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                source.Html = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            return source;
        }
    }
}
```

Por favor ayudenme.

Gracias

Comment: Tengo la curiosidad porque en Xamarin, elegis usar javascript o un webview para ejecutar algo, segun tengo entendido esta entre las practicas no recomendadas.

Comment: Tuve que integrar un software de terceros porque asi estaba en los requerimientos de este proyecto. Este software de terceros tiene años desarrollado y anteriormente funcionaba con UIWebview y EvaluateJavaScriptAsync sin problemas, sin embargo al realizarse el cambio a WKWebview dejo de funcionar. Lo que necesito es pasar el token que obtengo en el javascript al codigo de mi aplicacion al hacer el login para identificarlo, pero como ese token se obtiene abriendo el webview no se como identificar a que dispositivo tiene que ir si varios se conectan simultaneamente.